# Matching multi user

Tags: php, functions, users

I wanna matching two strings' user ID and show only matching user id...

```
$followers = get_user_meta($user_info->ID, '_Followers User ID');
$following = get_user_meta($user_ID, '_Following User ID');
$mf = ($followers = $following);
foreach($mf[0] as $fw){}
```

Comment: ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: i need show match id but this code not working